# Blender 2.79 problems adding Gear Addon on Mac

Tags: add-on, 3d-printing, osx

I have been going through tutorials online that seem simple enough but for some reason my 'add_mesh_gear.py' addon will not install. I have tried the text editor method in blender and the straight forward install from file and both appear to do something but nothing appears to actuakky install.

There's a message in the top right window that says:

```
Modules installed () from <my file directory> to <blender addons directory>
```

The empty parenthesis looks as if nothing was installed and, as I said originally, it does not appear in the addons list either.

Does anyone know what may be the issue?